# Decimal position using "Beats per minute" in taglib-sharp

Tags: vb.net, taglib-sharp

i'm using taglib-sharp to read BPM tag in a mp3 music folder. The code is like this:

```
Dim f As TagLib.File = TagLib.File.Create(File)
Dim bpm As String = f.Tag.BeatsPerMinute
```

The files BPM tag contains decimal numbers but the code returns an integer.

What can i do to solve?

Comment: What datatype is `BeatsPerMinute`? If you look at the Property in the Object Browser, you should be able to see the datatype.

Comment: Its a UInteger, so a tag value of 190.00 results in a string like 19000. I want to know if exists an option to read the tag like a custom tag, and store the value like a string or decimal and not loose the decimal position.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think a value of 190.00 would be possible for an UInteger. It would have to be a whole number. If the number is consistently 100 times higher then just divide by 100.

```
Private Sub Test()
    Dim i = 19000UI / 100
    Dim bpm = i.ToString("N2")
    Debug.Print(bpm)
End Sub

Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim f As TagLib.File = TagLib.File.Create(File)
    Dim bpm As String = f.Tag.BeatsPerMinute / 100.ToString("N2")
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, my English is very bad and you didn't understand me. 
The mp3 has a value of 190'00 stored in its "BPM" tag.
The code returns 19000.
A division by 100 would be valid if all the files had 2 decimals in the "BPM" tag but this is not the case. Some have values with only 1 decimal place or even without them.

Comment: @boisterious Can you provide a few more examples of the raw data you are getting back form the `BeatsPerMinute` property? I presume the values are not consistent.

Comment: In all cases, the value obtained is the one stored in the id3tag but eliminating the decimal separator. In my music library, i have files with values in the "bpm" tag like: xxx or xxx.x or xxx.xx

Comment: Temporary solution: recalculate all bpm with MixMeister BPM Analyzer. This application always inserts 2 decimal places. It is then possible to retrieve the label information with BeatsPerMinute and divide by 100.